# How handle variable-length output sequences in a simple BasicRNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to run a simple **BasicRNN model** in tensorflow with different input / output sizes. Input should have a shape of **[batch_size, 50, 2]**, output should have a shape of **[batch_size, 75, 2]**.

After finishing the example below with the same shape (in_length = out_length), I've tried to add the sequence_length parameter to the dynamic_rnn to predict larger output sequences, but it does not seem to work, since I always receive value erros when feeding the model.

```
in_length = 50
out_length = 75
num_inputs = 2
num_outputs = 2
hidden = 64
batch_size = 1024

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_length, num_inputs], name="Inputs")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_length, num_outputs], name="Labels")

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=hidden, activation=tf.nn.relu)

rnn_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, 
                                  x, 
                                  sequence_length=[in_length]*batch_size,
                                  dtype=tf.float32)

stacked_rnn_output = tf.reshape(rnn_output, [-1, hidden])
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_output, num_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, out_length, num_outputs])

...

batch = np.random.choice(N, batch_size, replace=False)
sess.run([training_op], feed_dict={x:x_batches[batch], y:y_batches[batch]})
```

**Value Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/timeseries/main.py", line 142, in <module>
    sess.run([training_op], feed_dict={x:x_batches[batch], y:y_batches[batch]})
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 961, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1024, 50, 2) for Tensor u'Inputs:0', which has shape '(?, 100, 2)'
```

Does someone has a hint for me? Do I have a general error in the understanding of different sequence lengths? I guess, these shapes should not be a problem for a dynamic_rnn...

---

**EDIT**

I've added the traceback, although I don't think, that this could help. It is definitly a problem in the 2nd dimension, I've resolved it, but it is not a correct solution for my model.

I updated my model by padding the input with zeros, so I have the same tensors for in- and output. The model does not crash with an value error anymore, but I expect that I can feed the network with 50 real values + 25 zeros = 75 and will receive 75 predicted values, because I'm using the sequence length parameter and I'm training the network with 75 real labels.
But the output is 50 real values and 25 zeros...

This should be a many-to-many / one-to-many problem, which I thought is no problem for a rnn...

Comment: If the length can change then you need to have a None in that dimension of the placeholder.

Comment: The lenght does not change during runtime, the model is only configurable for different in-/outputlength. The rnn needs to handle a few inputs and shall predict more outputs.

Comment: Where exactly does the error happen? Could you include the tracktrace?

Comment: Judging by the message, you have the 2nd dimension wrong. But without the stacktrace, it's hard to say where exactly it's wrong.